# Beginning Java: Printing out multiplication table

Tags: java

I am trying to print out a multiplication table of even numbers. Can anyone assist? I need someone to explain why I'm getting a strange result instead of the one that I want.

```
public class even {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
int i = 0;

while(i <= 10){
int j = 0; 
    while(j <= 10) {
        j+=2;
        System.out.print(i*j + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
    i+=2; 
}
}

}
```

The output that I want is to print out : 0,2,4,6,8 on the vertical axis and again on the horizontal axis. I want the chart to read like a multiplication table.

Comment: What is the output you are getting? What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: Hint: Using for loop would be very easy to do this program.

Comment: Why are you incrementing your counters by 2 on each step?  Might work if you only incremented by 1.

Comment: You are calling `j+=2` *before* printing the value, effectively resulting in values between 2 and 12 being printed instead of 0 to 10.

Comment: @Marvo The question specifies that it is limited to *even* numbers.

Comment: I need to use the while loop I've never learned the for loop in class

Comment: Unrelated but important - the first letter of the class name should be upper case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's this? I suspect your problem may be because you're adding to `j` before calculating the answer with `j+=2;`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int startAt = 2;

    for (int i = startAt; i <= 10; i += 2) {
        for (int j = startAt; j <= 10; j += 2) {
            System.out.print(i*j + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The use of the for loop is perfect here as it merges a few lines into one (variable initialization, while loop and variable increment).

Here it is with a `while` loop, it's not ideal though:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int startAt = 2;
    int i = startAt;

    while (i <= 10){
        int j = startAt; 

        while (j <= 10) {
            // Notice these lines are swapped!
            System.out.print(i*j + "\t");
            j+=2;
        }

        System.out.println();
        i+=2; 
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but how do I get rid of the zeroes? I see the logic here

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class WhileLoop
{   
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {

    int startAt = 1;
    int i = startAt;

    while (i <= 20){
        int j = startAt; 

        while (j <= 20) {
            // Notice these lines are swapped!
            System.out.print(i*j + "\t");
            j+=1;
        }

        System.out.println();
        i+=1; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will allow you to display a multiplication chart. You can change the value you want it by changing (  I <= 20 and j <= 20 to anything you want the size of it